# Create a Tabular Table

Tags: tables

I would like to develop a tabular table like this.
[image]

However, when I use the reference code from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables#Creating_a_simple_table_in_LaTeX , with code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth} { 
  | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X | }
 \hline
 Place/Transition & Explanation & Time  \\
 \hline
 T_1 and T_(2(n+1))  & Robot operation which relates to loadlocks. Transition T_1indicates that wafer unloading from the loadlocks and T_(2(n+1)) means that the robot loads the wafer to the loadlocks. & w \\
\hline
 item 31  & item 32  & item 33 \\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The result is as follows.

[image]

Perhaps, does anyone have any other reference to create a tabular table that I want, please?

When I Replace \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth} by \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} , here is the result:

[image]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `T_1` and `T_(2(n+1))` are supposed to be in math mode, right? While you're at it, shouldn't `T_(2(n+1))` be `T_{2(n+1)}`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But my main concern right now is not on the math mode of T_1 etc. My question is on the tabular table format, thank you.

Comment: Once you fix the math-mode syntax errors, your table will compile. Incidentally, you may find the table to be more pleasing to the eye if you use `l` and `c`, respectively, as the column types for the first and third columns.

Comment: as your image shows the t_1 is your main concern if you get any error the pdf is not intented to be usable.

Comment: Hi @Mico, do you mind explaining to me what is "l" and "c" and how to do so, please? Thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTI - The column types `l` and `c` stand for "left" and "center", respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, as stated in the comments, that you omit the necessary syntax for math mode. Because of this, TeX will at some point read a `_` which is only a valid character in math mode. Hence, it will switch to math mode automatically, but since it does not know where the math mode should end, it keeps typesetting in math mode which results in this strange output.

It is very easy to solve this problem by using the correct syntax for math mode. Since you don't need pragraphs in columns one and three, you could also switch to another column defintion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth} { |
  l |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
  c |
}
  \hline
  Place/Transition & Explanation & Time  \\
  \hline
  $T_1$ and $T_{2(n+1)}$  & Robot operation which relates to loadlocks. Transition $T_1$ indicates that wafer unloading from the loadlocks and $T_{2(n+1)}$ means that the robot loads the wafer to the loadlocks. & w \\
  \hline
  item 31 & item 32 & item 33 \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative solution could be created with the help of the `booktabs` package, which can help you reduce the amount of borders between cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth} { 
  l 
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
  c 
}
  \toprule
  Place/Transition & Explanation & Time  \\
  \midrule
  $T_1$ and $T_{2(n+1)}$  & Robot operation which relates to loadlocks. Transition $T_1$ indicates that wafer unloading from the loadlocks and $T_{2(n+1)}$ means that the robot loads the wafer to the loadlocks. & w \\
  item 31 & item 32 & item 33 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note that you might want to replace `0.8\textwidth` by `\linewidth` if you want to extend the table to the width of a text column in a two-column layout:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} { |
  l |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
  c |
}
  \hline
  Place/Transition & Explanation & Time  \\
  \hline
  $T_1$ and $T_{2(n+1)}$  & Robot operation which relates to loadlocks. Transition $T_1$ indicates that wafer unloading from the loadlocks and $T_{2(n+1)}$ means that the robot loads the wafer to the loadlocks. & w \\
  \hline
  item 31 & item 32 & item 33 \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\newpage

Right column

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Jasper , the overleaf template that I use now is \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} with two columns. What should I add on the code that you provided so that the table could be fit into the template? thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTI Replace `\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}` by `\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}`, and you could maybe use a smaller font for the tabulars, if you want to put larger amounts of text in there.

Comment: Hi @jasper , I used \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} , however the table does not change. I put the screenshot by updating the question above. thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTI This should rather be asked as a new question, I fear. I cannot see what you are doing in your code. I can just tell you what works for me (see my edit). Also, maybe have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/47927

Comment: Hi @jasper, I posted it as a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/676901/288908 , thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idea that's complementary to the second table in [@JasperHabicht's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676891/5001): Get rid of the whitespace padding at either end, and allow line breaks in column 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newlength\mylen

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\settowidth\mylen{Transition} % target width of column 1
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth} {@{} 
     >{\RaggedRight}p{\mylen} >{\RaggedRight}X c @{}}
 \toprule
 Place\slash Transition & Explanation & Time  \\
 \midrule
 $T_1$ and $T_{2(n+1)}$  & 
 Robot operation which relates to loadlocks. Transition $T_1$ indicates that wafer unloading from the loadlocks, and $T_{2(n+1)}$ means that the robot loads the wafer to the loadlocks. & 
 $w$ \\
 \addlinespace
 item 31 & item 32 & item 33 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```