# Table in Two Column Template

Tags: tables

I would like to create a tabular table by using the following code.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { |
  l |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
  c |
}
  \hline
  Place/Transition & Explanation & Time  \\
  \hline
  $T_1$ and $T_{2(n+1)}$  & Robot operation which relates to loadlocks. Transition $T_1$ indicates that wafer unloading from the loadlocks and $T_{2(n+1)}$ means that the robot loads the wafer to the loadlocks. & w \\
  \hline
  item 31 & item 32 & item 33 \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Here is the result.

[image]

Questions:
(1) How to make sure all the table fit in the two column template?
(2) How can I add more row in the table?

Thank you.

Comment: You should replace `\textwidth` with `\linewidth` as I suggested [in the other thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676891/47927). The difference is that `\textwidth` returns the width of the text body spanning over both columns, while `\linewidth` returns the width of the current box (in this case a the relevant column). Do you want to break the tabular over several columns?

Comment: I thought `\columnwidth` works too?

Comment: @User23456234 Yes, it does. `\linewidth` returns the width of the current outer box, therefore it would also work inside a `\parbox`. In this case, both should return the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you (a) set the width of the `tabularx` environment to `\columnwidth` and (b) allow line-breaking in column 1 as well, by switching from an `l` to a `p` column type. To allow a line break in the header of column 1, I suggest you change `Place/Transition` to `Place\slash Transition`.

When working with the IEEEtran document class, I further suggest you employ a package, such as `newtxmath`, that provides a Times Roman *math font*. I would also try to give the table a more open and inviting "look", by getting rid of all vertical lines and creating fewer, but well-spaced horizontal rules

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman text and math fonts
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight macro

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Transition} % target width of column 1

\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25} % <-- I wouldn't do that

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth} {@{} 
     >{\RaggedRight}p{\mylen} 
     >{\RaggedRight}X 
     c @{}}
  \toprule
  Place\slash Transition & Explanation & Time  \\
  \midrule
  $T_1$ and $T_{2(n+1)}$  & 
  Robot operation which relates to loadlocks. Transition $T_1$ indicates that wafer unloading from the loadlocks, and $T_{2(n+1)}$ means that the robot loads the wafer to the loadlocks. & 
  $w$ \\
  \addlinespace
  item 31 & item 32 & item 33 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```